# Django form for model of models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following models to define a Customer.  I figured for reusability to separate out the address and 'person' fields into separate models.  Since Customer contains a Person which in turn contains an Address, how can I make a CreateView for Customer?  Not quite understanding how to use something like inline_formset to achieve what I want.

models.py:

```
import localflavor.us.models as us_models
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

class Address(models.Model):
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    house_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = us_models.USStateField()
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)


class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('date created')
    home_phone = us_models.PhoneNumberField()
    work_phone = us_models.PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    cell_phone = us_models.PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, primary_key=True)


class Customer(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, primary_key=True, default=None)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your address field, its quite straight forward and you probably want to [look at using an inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). There is a fair bit of code required for it, but the tutorial is quite straight forward.

However, for the Person/Customer issue, don't forget that models are first and foremost Python objects so you can use lots of OOP inheritance principles. If a `Customer` *is* a `Person` document that:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # ... fields trimmed ...
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, primary_key=True)

class Customer(person):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
```

Here we've clearly defined the relationship, and the relation is taken care behind the scenes. However, an important caveat, the name and adderss are still in the `Person` table, so queries for `Person`s would return `Customer`s too.

Another alternative is [using an abstract class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes), like so:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # ... fields trimmed ...
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, primary_key=True)

class Customer(person):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
class Retailer(person):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
```

Now, the Person object won't get a database table, and can only be used through inheritance - so we can query for `Customer`s or `Retailer`s, but not `Person`s.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response!  Very good point on Customer is a Person.  I went with the abstract route as its more appropriate for my use case.  I still don't quite see how to create the form for the HAS A relationship, Customer has an Address in this case.  The link you provided just had said to use the inlineformset_factory(Address, Customer) and set form equal to that Set within the view.  Now the form displays all the fields for Person but just has Address as a drop down list of objects to select from instead of displaying all the fields for the Address too.